# NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString returns unexpected values

Tags: ios, foundation, nsnumberformatter

I've met an issue when using NSNumberFormatter. In two system language settings, I get two different results.

Say the system language is Vietnamese now. When the value is "1.111", which contains the currencyGroupingSeparator, `numberFromString` returns nil. But when the value is "111", which doesn't contain the currencyGroupingSeparator, `numberFromString` returns `NSNumber`(1.111) as expected .

The weird thing is when the system language is English, both "1.111" and "111" can be converted by `numberFromString` to expected `NSNumber(1.111 and 111).

Do I misuse NSNumberFormatter?

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.currencySymbol = ""
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = "."
formatter.currencyDecimalSeparator = ","
let testNumber = formatter.numberFromString("1.111")

// nil when system language is Vietnamese,
// but 1.111 when system language is English 
print("\(testNumber)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just force the locale for the formatter, then it will be the same for all cases:

`formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")`